# Spark Scala Populate Dataframe from Select query result

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

Let's say I have a two tables, one for students (`tbl_students`) and another for exams (`tbl_exams`). In vanilla SQL with a relational database, I can be able to use an outer join to find the list of students who have missed a particular exam, since the `student_id` won't match any row in the exam table for a that particular `exam_id`. I could also insert the result of this outer join query into another table using the `SELECT INTO` syntax.

With that background, can I be able to achieve a similar result using spark sql and scala, where I can populate a dataframe using the result of an outer join? Example code is (the code is not tested and may not run as is):

//Create schema for single column

`val schema = StructType(
   StructField("student_id", StringType, true)
 )`

//Create empty RDD

`var dataRDD = sc.emptyRDD`

//pass rdd and schema to create dataframe

`val joinDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dataRDD, schema);
joinDF.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl_students_missed_exam");`

//Populate tbl_students_missed_exam dataframe using result of outer join

`sparkSession.sql(s"""
SELECT tbl_students.student_id
INTO tbl_students_missed_exam
FROM tbl_students
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_exams ON tbl_students.student_id = tbl_exams.exam_id;""")`

Thanks in advance for your input

Comment: You can't dot that. You should create new DataFrame from the join by filtering where `student_id` is null

Comment: I agree with you @blackbishop, I ended up using an approach like you are suggesting. The dataframe with the join results was created implicitly by the operation.

`val students = sparkSession.sql("select students query"):
val exams = sparkSession.sql("select exams query"):

val missed_exam = students.join(exams, exams("fk_student_id") === students("student_id"), "left outer")
where("other criteria needed");

missed_exam.show();`

I was then able to use the new dataframe for further processing